# How do I wrap link router with back-ticks to a card and pass a variable to it Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi everyone am still learning React and this is my recipe project >>Practicing react<<

[image: Recipe app]

The project fetches data from a recipe API endpoint and display them the homepage component. The homepage component(where state the is managed), sends data to a recipe component after mapping through the data

[image: Recipe]

And this is the recipe Component

[image: Recipe component]

Am trying to wrap the content in a link in such a way that when you click a certain item it displays the information of the specific item like Link to=`/${some variable}`(wrapped within back-ticks) but it wont work, I need help

Comment: what will be the value of link to .Have you created a route for the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add you route like

```
<Route path="/:id" exact component={ComponentName}></Route>
```

and then in

```
<Link to={`/${variable}`}>
            <your code>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<Link to={`/${someVariable}`} >
  <WrappedComponent />
</Link>
```